# Periodically export data from google-play with script

Tags: android, google-play-console

I want to export information about crashes and ANR from google play console with script. I want to get how many crashes happened on specific day on what device and on what version of application.

I managed to create service account on google play console and can export reports from Download Reports tab and also get information about crashes and ANR with python code. The problem is that I cannot connect crashes with both device and version. So I want to get a table with all below informations.

**Date, App version, Device, Daily Crashes, Daily ANR**

Is it even possible? Inside google play console this can be done by setting a filter to App version. I am interested only in last version.

Comment: Is maybe python Selenium the right answer?

Comment: I also ask play console support and it seams there is no solution to my problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.